# Can bitbake incrementally compile only modified sources within a recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

If there are 3 source files:

- `a.cpp`
- `b.cpp`
- `c.cpp`

Let's say these three go in `x1.so` symbol file.

If there are 5 other `.so` files, `x2.so`, `x3.so`, `x4.so`, `x5.so` made from other source files.

If I modify `a.cpp`, I expect only `x1.so` to (re) compile,

but what I see is that, bitbake compiles all libs in that package

In recipe S path they are triggered together like:

- add_subdirectory(x1/Cmakelists.txt bin_out_path)
- add_subdirectory(x2/Cmakelists.txt bin_out_path)
- add_subdirectory(x3/Cmakelists.txt bin_out_path)
- add_subdirectory(x4/Cmakelists.txt bin_out_path)
- add_subdirectory(x5/Cmakelists.txt bin_out_path)

Is there any way to avoid compiling unmodified sources?

I considered refactoring, but it's not just 5 libs, there are about 50 libs in that package.

Comment: Maybe you should try to build the specific recipe with command as follows (note that it is relevant in BitBake 1.30 and later): `bitbake -c compile -f -S myrecipe`